# React state change best practices: useEffect vs callback

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a question regarding best practices when using useEffect and when to use it to handle state changes.

For example let's say I have a button that will send an email on the 5th click (pseudo code as I didn't really test to see if it works). What's better according to React best practices.

Here I am using **useEffect** to handle the count state change:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
export default () => {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
    useEffect(() => {
        if (count === 5) {
            sendEmail()
            setCount(0)
        }
    }, [count])

    return (
        <div>
            <input
                type="button"
                onClick={() => {
                    setCount((count) => count + 1)
                }}
            ></input>
        </div>
    )    
}
```

Here is the same functionality with a **callback**:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
export default () => {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
   
    return (
        <div>
            <input
                type="button"
                onClick={() => {
                    if(count + 1 === 5) {
                        sendEmail()
                        setCount(0)
                        return
                    }
                    setCount(count=>count+1)
                }}
            ></input>
        </div>
    )    
}
```

The argument for using useEffect, at least as I see it, is to react to state changes. However if I want to check other state in that useEffect block or other dependencies, then I have to add it to the dependency array and it's in danger of re-running even though I'm only interested in running it in response to the count changing (one piece of state). In this example it isn't too egregious but in more advanced situations it seems that you have to add a bunch of conditionals in the useEffect block if you only want it to react to one piece of state change. if(x,y,z) {run count logic}

The argument for the callback is that it's readable and will only be called on the button being pressed however it is more imperative than declarative and not as REACTive as useEffect. Furthermore with the setCount being async it might create a race condition (not in this case but in more advanced cases).

Also I can use useEffect to run code when a component has first rendered but if it has logic that touches dependencies I have to add them to the dependency array according to my linter and Dan Abramov but then I run the chance of running it multiple times unless I add a bunch of conditionals in the body of useEffect (as I mentioned above). In short I may want to run the useEffect on one piece of state change and not when any of the dependencies change.

I hope that makes sense.

An example of the useEffect issue with conditionals is if I want to send the email if some localState variable === "whatever". Once I add the localState variable into the dep array, then it will run whenever it changes even if I only want to run it when specific state (count) changes. The only way around this I see is adding logic on the useEffect to exit early but it starts to get complicated and error prone.

Comment: Voting to close as opinion-based. As you can see, you've already two out of two conflicting answers. This is a subjective question. Do what makes sense to you, is easy to read and maintain, on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: @Drew Reese they seem to have real consequences between the 2. I think the callback functionality can't reactively or declaratively handle state as well especially if we need to call functions on page lifecycle methods i.e. when the component mounts but the useEffect has the dependency issue where we unintendedly run the useEffect when dependencies change even if that's not the intended consequence.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant by using your best judgement on a case-by-case basis for what actually needs to be accomplished. There is no single fits-all solution for your question.

Comment: @DrewReese how do you get around those limitations though?

Comment: Sorry, can you be more specific? What limitations are you referring to? Do you have a more specific use case that needs to be addressed? It seems it all still depends specifically on what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

In your kind of situation, it's better to just call sendmail within your click function (option 2) to avoid unnecessary rerendering.

With regards to question of "race condition", instead of using setCount(0), you can always use a `ref` to store the count. You can use `ref` to store the count since you do not need to trigger a rerender when your count changes.

Otherwise, instead of resetting to 0, you can always do

```
if ((count % 5) === 0) {
 sendmail()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with option 1. If you want to run other effects off of some state you can have a separate useEffect block for that, so your count block only runs when the count state changes.